# Adding Power Functions to LEGO Mack Anthem Truck (42078)

Tags: technic, power-functions

Does anyone have experience adding *Power Functions* to set *#42078 LEGO Mack Anthem* truck?

It’s a *Technic* set, but only features manually actuated functions.

I have seen it motorized on *YouTube*, even though a Power Function option is not mentioned on the box. Any details on how to do it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I modified the unit. It's quite intense. If you have built the unit you have to take a lot of it apart but it dose look cool running along. I’m about to buy a motor for the trailer. I’m going to get a independent motor with battery and switch and hold it on the back only because it a lot of turning on the cogs.

Answer (score 3):

There is this thread on Eurobricks:

[42078 Mack Anthem Mods and improvements](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/157208-42078-mack-anthem-mods-and-improvements/)

Also this youtube video

[KlikBriks Lego Technic MACK Anthem (RC MOD) l Instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSct7RQc6vo)

Answer (score 0):

There is an instruction on [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-12660/CustomBricks.de/custom-mack-rc-modification/) on how to motorize the truck. Please be aware that instructions are not free (I'm not affiliated with model designer).

[This](https://rebrickable.com/sets/compare/slow/?1-set=42078-1&1-inv=21270&1-user_list=&2-set=MOC-12660&2-inv=22749&2-user_list=) gives you list of parts you need to have to complete the motorization.

You can also check Rebrickable for other [42078 set](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/?q=42078) and [Mack](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/?q=mack) related modifications, alternate and unique models with instructions (free or paid) available for each of them.